# Is it good to return HTTP 500 in a RESTful API?

Tags: rest

When I write a RESTful API server, normally I do not return HTTP 500 in my code.
In my opion, HTTP 500 error means：

**some situation/exception that out of your control. You did not realize that error may happen**

If you realize that some error may happen, you will always can find some other HTTP CODE to represent it. 503 for example.

So I prefer not to return HTTP 500 manually. In that case if an 500 happens then I know it is some unhandled exception

Is this a good practice?

Comment: If you want to enable your clients to distinguish between 500 and 503, return different codes, but if you do not care why bother? Status codes are for communicating with a client, not for some magical standalone use.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it good to return HTTP 500 in a RESTful API?

I would't say it's *good*, but I would say it's *valid*.

It's important to keep in mind that [status codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) are meant to represent the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's request. You can read more about the status codes in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) but, in a nutshell, this is what the HTTP status codes mean according to their range:

- `1xx`: Hold on
- `2xx`: Here you go
- `3xx`: Go away
- `4xx`: You f*cked up
- `5xx`: I f*cked up

If the server failed to fulfill an apparently valid request, it's better to return a status code in the `5xx` range than *masking* the actual error with another status code that may lead clients to confusion. Don't return status codes in the `2xx` or in the `4xx` range if the client's request is valid.

> So I prefer not to return HTTP 500 manually.

Depending on the architecture of your application, you may want to have a layer to catch any unhandled exceptions and translate them to status codes. Depending on the exception, you may want to return a status code in the `5xx` range.

And you may also find useful to return in the response some sort of *correlation identifier* to your logs, so it can help you to spot what has occurred to your application.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it good to return HTTP 500 in a RESTful API?

It's fine.  [500 Internal Server Error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) has broadly applicable semantics.

I think the key idea is this: when the problem is at the server, there's not a lot that the client (or the intermediary components) can do to improve the situation.

Certainly, you shouldn't be using a 500 status code when the fault is in the request.  Distinguishing 4xx from 5xx is a lot more important than distinguishing 500 from 50x.

For server errors, I would expect you to choose 500 unless some other code were a clearly better fit (ex: 503 for temporary conditions where Retry-After semantics are likely to prove useful).